# Deployement on a Django Api

Tags: django, apache, api

I'm actually developping a Django Rest API with the djangoRestFramework, I configured followed many tutorials and finally configured it. For the next step, I tried to deploy the API on an Apache web server.
Here is my wsgi.py :

```
    """
WSGI config for take_care_api project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named application.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'take_care_api.settings')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My 000-default.conf :

```
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi_python3.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin renoidur@localhost

#   DocumentRoot /etc/take_care_api/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /static /api/site/static

    ErrorLog /api/site/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /api/site/logs/access.log combined
    
    
    <Directory /api/take_care_api/take_care_api/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess take_care_api python-path=/api/take_care_api/
    WSGIProcessGroup take_care_api
    WSGIScriptAlias / /api/take_care_api/take_care_api/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

When I tried to access to my django project trought the browser, I received this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at renoidur@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 9000
```

error.log :

```
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772216 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108] mod_wsgi (pid=19400): Failed to exec Python script file '/api/take_care_api/take_care_api/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772284 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108] mod_wsgi (pid=19400): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/api/take_care_api/take_care_api/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772410 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772447 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]   File "/api/take_care_api/take_care_api/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772452 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772459 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772463 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772469 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772473 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772479 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772483 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sun Mar 07 18:06:37.772498 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 19400:tid 140138505574144] [remote ::1:36108] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

I'm a newbie so I dont't really understand what is wrong with my code.Also, I don't use Virtualenv.
Thank you very much.